# Creating a requirements.txt for python 3.11.3

Tags: heroku, runtime, requirements.txt

I have a python 3.7.6. Heroku only allows python-3.9.16 , python-3.10.11 , and python-3.11.3 . How can I create a requirements.txt without updating my python version?

I need the compatible versions of:

- certifi
- click
- dataclass
- Flask
- Flask-SQLAlchemy
- greenlet
- gunicorn
- importlib-metadata
- itsdangerous
- Jinja2
- MarkSafe
- SQLAlchemy
- typingextensions
- Werkzueg
- zipp

Comment: Why don't you want to upgrade your Python version? Python 3.7 [is about to go out of support anyway](https://devguide.python.org/versions/). And most code written for 3.7 should work just fine in 3.9, 3.10, or 3.11.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `pip freeze > requirements.txt` if you are working with virtual environments and then install the latest version of Python and check compatibility (you can also test compatibility with online compilers like Google Cloab). If not, try searching [PYPI.ORG](https://pypi.org) for all the latest version compatibility, as far as I know, there is no way to do it automatically.
If you can't find a match for one of the things you need, you can find a replacement directory, or switch storage.